# Safe to run 2N2222A at 0.4 W? possible NPN alternatives to 2N2222A

Tags: transistors, cooling

The datasheet for my 2N2222A claims it can run at 0.5 W. I am running it at nearly .4W. My casing has good ventilation via a large fan. Should I search for a component which can handle more power, or stick with the 2N2222A? the circuit in question is this current limiter which is able to handle being short circuited.

[image]

Comment: Power rating alone is not the only consideration. Do the thermal resistance calculation to calculate the junction temperature at that power : while the specified abs max may be 125C, it may have a longer life if you limit it to 80 or 100C. If necessary, do the calculation again with a small heatsink.

Answer (score 1):

The data sheet specifies that its ABSOLUTE MAX rating is 0.5W.  So running it at 0.4W, as long as you are observing the other factors such as Tamb and Tc you should be OK.

Personally, though, I'd probably look at an alternate device and probably package that runs the device lower in its operating range.

Comment: What are you driving? If it is a switching load a MOSFET would cut the wattage to a very minimal amount. The 2N4400 or 01 would be a better fit and gives you some room on the wattage. I use them a lot with good results, that is why I chose it. Can you show your circuit?

Comment: @Gil i am showing my circuit